# Changing font colors within a beamer theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I'm using the [Stockholm (`sthlm`) Beamer theme](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/stockholm-beamer-theme/xjysnqdxfjbc#.Vf8Hm9wVhBf).  The template for this theme shows how to use its Light Yellow font color:

```
\setbeamercolor{sthlmLightYellow}{fg=sthlmLightYellow,bg=white}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\linewidth,ht=2ex,dp=0.7ex]{sthlmLightYellow}
    \texttt{sthlmLightYellow}
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

My question is, how would I set a single word in a line of text to be `sthlmLightYellow`, leaving the other words black?  And suppose I wanted to have a few colors in this line -- how would I achieve that?

This is what I've come up with:

```
\setbeamercolor{sthlmLightYellow}{fg=sthlmLightYellow, bg=white}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\linewidth, ht=2ex, dp=0.7ex]{sthlmLightYellow}
  \centerline{\texttt{Merkel cells} {\color{black} and}
    {\color{cyan} \texttt{A$\beta$ sensory neurons}}
    {\color{black} form Merkel cell-neurite complexes.}}
```

But I feel like there's got to be a simpler way.

Comment: With `\textcolor{<selected color>}{colored text}`?

Comment: @dbliss Does the comment from Zarko answer your question?

Comment: @dbliss: Zarko's comment was made soon after you posted the question. You gave no feedback on it -- Perhaps nobody can work with the fragments you provided, now three months later the question is unclear. That's why we like to have feedback by comments/votes/accepts.

Comment: @dbliss, what job you expect from me? To wrote an answer? You not respond on my comment, so I concluded that it doesn't work for you. When I use suggested solution it always wars! Anyway, I will convert my comment to answer ....

Answer (score 2):

Regardless to Beamer theme you can always change font color with:

```
\textcolor{<selected color>}{colored text}
```

This is valid for any document class, not only for Beamer. Of course, for this command the preamble of document should explicit or implicit loaded `color` or `xcolor` package.

To show, how this will work in your case, please provide minimal working example. I will insert in it an example of this command use.